# Realm - Swift cannot find protocol declaration ( -to many relationship )

Tags: realm

I got a little problem with my Realm database.

Here is one of my RLMObject ( RLMContact ) :

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(RLMContact)

@interface RLMContact : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;

@end
```

And here is an other one ( RLMGroup ) which has a 1-to-many relationship with RLMContact :

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import "RLMContact.h"

@interface RLMGroup : RLMObject

@property NSString *number;

@property RLMArray<RLMContact> *contacts;

@end
```

I got the error message :

> Cannot find protocol declaration for RLMContact

pointing out this line : `@property RLMArray<RLMContact> *contacts;`

I have to say that I declare these "relationships" the same way for other RLMObjects and I don't have any problem.

Do you see anything wrong in my code ?

I use Objective-C and Swift in my project and all my RLMObjects are included in my bridging header.

An other thing : this RLMContact object is the only one I am not able to set as a relationship in my other RLMObjects.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT :

Finally, I just found out that it was working with some RLMObjects but not all of them. Really weird.

Comment: Are you still running into this issue?

Comment: I am have the same issue here. How did resolve this?

Comment: This is likely a problem with how your `#import`s are set up in your project. I've uploaded a small sample project with the same model definitions that you can download and compare with here: https://static.realm.io/debug/ArrayType.tgz